# Native dll version conflict in referenced .net assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, dll, native

I need to reference two assemblies in my .NET program:

- The first assembly, namely `ILNumerics`, directly references native `hdf5.dll` library (version 1.8.17) by mean of `dllimport("hdf5.dll")` platform invoke.
- The second assembly, of my own, is a .net wrapper on top native matlab runtime libraries, but this native runtime also internally makes use of native `hdf5.dll` library (version 1.8.12) *[required when working with hdf5 data from matlab side]*.

Note also that native `hdf5.dll` library also depends on `hdf5_hl.dll` and `zlib.dll`.

I have tried to keep only one version of `hdf5.dll` library and dependencies and also to set environment variable `HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK` to `2` when starting my application but I can't escape from abrupt crash as I need to use hdf5 handling from both `ILNumerics` and `Matlab runtime` sides.

Is there a way I can cheat `"dllimport("hdf5.dll")"` in `ILNumerics` assembly to alias some other name ? Note, I don't have the sources, so i cannot hard recompile with `dllimport("hdf5_1_8_17.dll")`, same for matlab runtime library, I cannot changed anything in it (again third party + native code). What about, *in case cheating `hdf5.dll` name in `ILNumerics` would be possible*, the indirect reference to `hdf5_hl.dll` from `hdf5.dll` ?

I guess my only last option is to use load `ILNumerics` and `Matlab runtime` assemblies in different applications domains, but then this would be "hell" because I will need to serialize data when calling one or another assembly exposed routine, right ? (I have never worked with separate application domains)

Comment: AppDomains won't help you in case of native libraries.

Comment: @ArieR I thought loading each assembly in their own domain would help loading twice dependent native libraries in separate memory areas, but maybe ...